# how can I collect my app user's position?

Tags: android, api

I am developing an android application for carpoling and I am using HERE as map provider.
In order to offer to user's the appropriate rides, I need to gather their position.

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will have to ask for user permission and the user must grant it first. check the [location documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location).

if you are going to need to use Google APIs like Google routes. read about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/routes).
there is a walkthrough on how to request location updates [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates)

I hope this helps. if you still need more clarifications. tell me in the comments!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
 How can I get these data (store it in a database)

Comment: you can store the longitude and latitude values. if my answer was helpful please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.